# NSInternalInconsistencyException: no section at index 4

Tags: iphone, core-data

Hi I have a simple database app on the iPhone that uses core data. I was just looking at some Flurry exception reports and I'm seeing the following error:

NSInternalInconsistencyException: no section at index 4

The number varies in the reports, but it is always the same message. Any idea on what this means and where to start my debugging efforts?

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that you have a tableview which is asking for a non existent section. Most likely, you are returning incorrect values from `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` for some reason.

Comment: I would agree, that is the only thing that sounds close.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but it's the top hit on Google - so here's a slightly more concise answer:

I've had this error message appear when an incorrect value is passed into `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `objectAtIndexPath:`

You pass in a `NSIndexPath` object, which probably has a section index which is beyond the value that you returned from `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

Answer (score 0):

try to use 
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:0];

instead of 
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:item];